# YouTube Data API results differ from YouTube search bar results

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I was trying out the YouTube Data API and after trying different query searches I found out that especially with filters the API returns different results than my YouTube Data API. Is there a reason for that?

For example I tried to get the most viewed Videos with the query string "Cooking":

```py
    try:
        response = service.search().list(
            part='snippet',
            type='video',
            order='viewCount',
            q='Cooking',
            maxResults=10
        ).execute()
```

it seems to return Videos with high view counts but nothing close to the view counts I get when I type "Cooking" in the YouTube search bar with the filters "video" and sort by "view count". Can someone explain how to fix it or why it doesn't work?

Comment: YouTube Data API v3 doesn't work well, I recommend you to webscrap, as [my open-source API proposes](https://github.com/Benjamin-Loison/YouTube-operational-API/blob/b4497dd70790ee44677106078c9858eb995df0e2/search.php).