# How does the YouTube Data API Search Endpoint request work with an empty query (q)?

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

Lets say I would like to get the Top 10 most viewed videos of all time, how would I do that?

Doesnt really work well with the video endpoint, so I tried it with the search endpoint and set the order parameter to "viewCount" & the type parameter to "video". But when I leave the query empty I get weird results like videos that are not even close to being the most viewed videos. It would be helpful if someone could explain how the endpoint works when the query is empty or if it may be related to my other question: [YouTube Data API results differ from YouTube search bar results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77002387/youtube-data-api-results-differ-from-youtube-search-bar-results)